# How do I place text to the right of a heading in OpenOffice.org?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice

I'm writing a CV using the Word processor of OpenOffice 2.4 (the version in the normal Ubuntu Gutsy (maybe using backports, I can't remember)).

I'd like to have text in the **Timeperiod** style (yellow background) which I would like to have to the right of text in the **Heading 2** style. My reason is that I want to conserve vertical space.

Using a table with invisible borders seems like cheating and semantically incorrect. Is there another, more correct way? (Note: I'm using the table approach in the meantime, as getting the CV done is more important. But I'm still curious about the answer and will adjust the document in case there is a better way.)

[image]

Comment: So you want to get the blue and yellow lines on exactly the same level, not one underneath another, and have the right-aligned timedate in a different font and size to the heading on the left?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a text frame to the end of the heading, and assign some frame style to it that lets it appear on the end of the current line (and with an invisible border). Still cheating, but IMHO better than a table.

You will have to take care about these lines not overlapping yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tab stops](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Setting_tab_stops_and_indents).

Comment: It does not seem to work. I put in a tab stop and I'm able to write more text on the same line. But as Heading 1 is a paragraph style the rest of the line will also be of the same style. And I want the style **Timeperiod** to the right of a **Heading 1** on the same line. But thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the **Heading 2** and **Timeperiod** lines.
2. Open the **Format->Columns** menu.
3. Change the number of columns to '2', and click OK.

You may need to play around with line spacing a little to make it look exactly right, but this will enable you to have two headings with different styles on the same line on the page.